# Flutter - speech to Text listen korean word

Tags: flutter

```
void initializeSpeechRecognition() async {
    try {
      var permission = await Permission.microphone.request();

      if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        var result = await speech.initialize();
        if (result) {
          speech.listen(
            onResult: (val) =>
                setState(() => transcription = val.recognizedWords),
            localeId: 'ko_KR',
          );
        }
      } else {
        print('Error: microphone permission denied');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }
```

I am trying to make the user speak korean and the app did not ask my permission to speak at the microphone, they show I denied permission before asking me, but when I try using the default English language there is no error occur, please check my code, many thanks.

This is the package I am using:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very strange, if its not even allowing you to use the microphone, if you set the language to korean. Can you check if korean language is installed on the device?

You can also try `var locales = await speech.locales();` to get the list of locales installed on your device.
Then you can try to start the app with english, then after page load you can change the locale either manually or by the code.

This is some sample code as written in their documentation.

```
var locales = await speech.locales();

    // Some UI or other code to select a locale from the list
    // resulting in an index, selectedLocale

    var selectedLocale = locales[selectedLocale];
    speech.listen(
        onResult: resultListener,
        localeId: selectedLocale.localeId,
        );
```

[speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text)